# ScriptAssert.List message from messages.properties

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have

```
@ScriptAssert.List({
    @ScriptAssert(lang="javascript",script="_this.email.equals(_this.confirmEmail)",message="email no match"),
    @ScriptAssert(lang="javascript",script="_this.password.equals(_this.confirmPassword)",  message="password no match")
```

I want to load the message from messages.properties  ,
I success doing this with

`ScriptAssert.signupBean=WORKING`

which works , but it's for both cases , how I can seperate ?
something like

`ScriptAssert.signupBean.$1=EMAIL.`..

`ScriptAssert.signupBean.$2=PASSWORD....`.

I tried to play with alias , with no success. ( using Spring MVC )

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your problem entirely, but if you want to show custom localized validator messages, everything you have to do is to put ValidationMessages.properties file at the root of your jar, change your code slightly

```
@ScriptAssert.List({
@ScriptAssert(lang="javascript",script="_this.email.equals(_this.confirmEmail)",message="{email.match.error}"),
@ScriptAssert(lang="javascript",script="_this.password.equals(_this.confirmPassword)",  message="{password.match.error}")
```

and put appropriate lines in your ValidationMessages.properties file

```
mail.match.error=Email and email confirmation does not match
password.match.error=Password and password confirmation does not match
```

That's it. Hope this helps